# Windows cmd line rename removes zeros from filenames?

Tags: windows, shell, rename

I have a bunch of files that I need to rename :

- XX_20_0001.pdf
- XX_20_0001.xml
- XX_20_0023.pdf
- XX_20_0023.jpg, etc.

I made a bat file with this code in it:

```
rename "XX_20_*" "XX_083_*"
```

But for some reason it only leaves three digits at the end of the file name:

XX_083_001.pdf

Why? and how can I change this?
Thank you!
Maria

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For DOS `ren SourceMask TargetMask`, the `TargetMask` is processed against the `SourceMask` (source name) strictly from left to right with no back-tracking. As `083` is one character longer than `20`, so DOS will "**eat**" one character.