# Rename file on Command Prompt

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have file like this and would like to rename:
Original File: `14876128.AOB.A14R2229-A14S2229.USER.pdf`
Would like to rename like this: `14876128.AOB.A14R2229...A14S2229.051922.USER.pdf`

`14876128.AOB.A14R2229` will stay the same as in original file name.
`-` will replace with `...` (three dots).
`A14S2229` will stay the same as in original file name.
`USER` will stay the same as in original file name.
Insert date before `USER` and add `.` (dot).

I tried:

```
REN ????????.???.????????-????????.?????.pdf ????????.???.????????...????????.%date:~10,4%%date:~7,2%%date:~4,2%.?????.pdf
```

But works half part only, please advise. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is Powershell allowed? Still technically command line :)

Answer (score 0):

The command indeed works half part only, with the result being:
`14876128.AOB.A14R2229....052022..pdf`

The reason is that the destination name is processed against the source name strictly from left to right with no back-tracking. This simply means that you can shorten the name of the file when renaming it, but you are not allowed to make it bigger in length. (Check also: [Windows cmd line rename removes zeros from filenames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63833281/windows-cmd-line-rename-removes-zeros-from-filenames))

Try a different strategy like a batch script, where you can save parts of the filename and then construct the destination filename by renaming it without using wildcards.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new text file, and write the following lines in it:

```
@echo off
For %%f in (*-*) do call :-replace "%%f"
:-replace
if "%~1"=="" exit
set "OldName=%~n1"
set "NewName=%OldName:-=...%"
set "NewName=%NewName:.USER=%"
ren "%~1" "%NewName%.%date:~10,4%%date:~7,2%%date:~4,2%.USER%~x1"
```

Save it as a .bat script, put it in a folder that contains the files you want to modify, and run it from there.

This will replace all dashes (-) with three dots (...)

Comment: @KJ If so, you can Delete the penultimate line, and change the last line (provided that only the last 5 characters may change): `ren "%~1" "%NewName:~1,-5%.%date:~10,4%%date:~7,2%%date:~4,2%.%NewName:~-5%%~x1"`